# OpenOCD and stm32

Tags: microcontroller, rtos, openocd, stm32f7, chibios

My system: Windows 8, USB 3.0 ports.

I want to debug my stm32f7-disco  in ChibiStudio. After build I try to connect using OpenOCD and ST-Link, but get the following:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00161-g1725abc3c (2017-06-24-20:22)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 2000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : clock speed 1800 kHz
Error: libusb_open() failed with LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED
Info : STLINK v2 JTAG v27 API v2 SWIM v15 VID 0x0483 PID 0x374B
Info : using stlink api v2
Info : Target voltage: 3.224704
Warn : Silicon bug: single stepping will enter pending exception handler!
Info : stm32f7x.cpu: hardware has 8 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
```

I think problem in libusb and usb 3.0.

Comment: I think it is a common problem. Expect more surprises.

Comment: I dont see the problem looks like a good connection telnet in and start debuging.

Comment: What happened when you connected to it with telnet and sniffed around, halted, read some registers or memory, etc?